# Lyniate Rhapsody: Cannot find function toISOString in object

Tags: javascript

I am using a solution called [Rhapsody](https://www.lyniate.com/rhapsody/) made by Lyniate which has a JavaScript engine. I have the following code:

```js
var d = new Date();
var myDate = d.toISOString();

console.log(myDate)
```

However, on the platform I get an error:

```
Cannot find function toISOString in object Wed Jan 27 2021 09:10:12 GMT-0000 (GMT).
```

None of the Rhapsody support documents mention this and I've reached out to their support with little effect.

**EDIT**

So I got an answer of Reddit:

> Rhapsody uses Mozilla Rhino as its JS interpreter, and Rhino hasn't been updated in ages so lots of 'modern' JS stuff is missing.

Comment: It seems your code works here.

Comment: You code seems fine, maybe Date.prototype does not support such a function in your engine?

Comment: I'm unable to find any source about Rhapsody (by Orion). Is there any documentation out there (publically)? Otherwise it will be hard to guess, what's possible and what's not.

Comment: My bad - the company is now called: https://www.lyniate.com/rhapsody/

Comment: Are you using a framework, if so are you importing anything at the top called Date?

Comment: Apparently: "Rhapsody uses Mozilla Rhino as its JS interpreter, and Rhino hasn't been updated in ages so lots of 'modern' JS stuff is missing."

Comment: If you've found a solution, you can write a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I made an edit to focus on this being a platform problem. Feel free to [rollback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271934) or [edit] the post if you disagree with the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use the Polyfill from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

```
if (!Date.prototype.toISOString) {
  (function() {

    function pad(number) {
      if (number < 10) {
        return '0' + number;
      }
      return number;
    }

    Date.prototype.toISOString = function() {
      return this.getUTCFullYear() +
        '-' + pad(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) +
        '-' + pad(this.getUTCDate()) +
        'T' + pad(this.getUTCHours()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getUTCMinutes()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getUTCSeconds()) +
        '.' + (this.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1000).toFixed(3).slice(2, 5) +
        'Z';
    };

  })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Rhapsody have a function called `dateChangeFormat' available in the JavaScript that can help output a date in the format of your choice.